# Select intersecting polygon in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, overlapping-features, select-by-location

We're trying to select an entire polygon if any part of it intersects a buffer in QGIS. How can I do this? I can get the intersecting part but can't figure out how to get the entire polygon.

To be more specific, I have a layer with polygons and a separate layer with lines that are buffered. I want to select all the polygons that intersect the buffers.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Since selecting a *whole* polygon is easier than selecting a part of one, you really need to specify what you are doing to be told what you are doing wrong.

Comment: Yes, like @Vince said: It would indeed be good to know what you have tried. Maybe you used some geoprocessing tool that creates a layer with the intersected portions of the polygons? Anyway, I added the most common solution as answer already.

Answer (score 3):

Use "Select by Location":

[image: "Select by Location" icon]

- "Select features from": your polygon layer
- "Where the features": check "intersect"
- "By comparing the features from": your buffer layer

[image: "Select by Location" dialogue]

That's it.

[image: Selected polygons]